# In Gnome is it possible to Invoke the network manager tool from the command line?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, mate-desktop, xmonad

Note: I was sent here by Stack Overflow.

I have a workstation using xmonad + Gnome + Mate on Linux Mint. The Gnome setup I have comes with a network management applet in the tray, however when I transition to Xmonad as my Window manager (while retaining the gnome layer) I lost access to the tray. Is it possible to invoke the applet directly from the command line so that I can configure my network settings with a GUI? I have found many bits of Gnome functionality can be invoked on the command line this way. For the life of me I can't figure out the name of the application mate is invoking to do the network management.

Of course I could just suck it up and configure my network from the command line (which is what I am doing now) - I'm just curious if I can cause the familiar menu to spawn in my xmonad setup, or if it is tied to the existence of the tray.

Is it possible? How could I do it?

Comment: I don't know the specific command for gnome, but I figured it out on my Mint install by doing `ps aux | grep -i network` and then opening the panel and running the command again, and noted which process spawned once the panel was open.

Comment: AFAIK the applet itself is called `nm-applet` however if you want to actually configure a connection probably what you want is the `nm-connection-editor` that it spawns when you click it (both part of the Ubuntu `network-manager-gnome` package)

Comment: If you were asked to move the question here, at least delete the other on StackOverflow so there are not duplicates and cross posts.

Comment: @steeldriver I have found that I cannot actually invoke nm-applet from inside xmonad + gnome. It just hangs. Other nm-tools like nm-connection-editor work, but I was looking for the one where I could restart connections, switch networks etc...